# Programmatically control breakpoints in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints

Is it possible, in any browser, using any plugin, to enable or disable breakpoints in your code programmatically?

I already know about setting conditional breakpoints, but I'm really interested in setting them via code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a javascript breakpoint in code - in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome) if only the title contained the keyword "code" SEO gods would have ruled otherwise :-)

Answer (score 30):

First you could add a call to a function like __checkDebug(); which will check for a global (or semi-global) variable and when said variable is true, call debugger.

```
  
function __checkDebug() {
   if (debugme) debugger;
}
```

all of your functions you're concerned about debugging would be like so:

```
  
function foo() {
   __checkDebug();

   //.... whatever foo was gonna do.
}
```

You can then take it a little further and dynamically decorate functions while the code is being executed like so:

```
Function.prototype.debug = function(){   
   var fn = this; 
   return function(){     
       if (debugme) debugger; 
       return fn.apply(this, arguments);     
   }; 
}; 

foo = foo.debug();
```

now any time foo is called it will call debugger if the debugme variable is truthy.

Another option would be to build a javascript build system that injects the call after every function declaration - this requires a syntax parser but if you're only looking to modify functions a simple tokenizer for that use case is pretty easy to write - but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `debugger;` in code to make breakpoint for firebug. For example:

```
alert('1');
debugger;
alert('2');
```

And firebug automatically stops on this keyword.

Comment: Works also in firebug console!

Comment: Yep, that is handy, but it's not really as programmatic as I need: eg, dynamically adding a breakpoint at the start of any arbitrary function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the FireBug functions *debug*(fn) & *undebug*(fn) names which set a breakpoint on the first line of the named function.

See point #6:

http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging

Comment: Can this be executed from the Javascript itself, or is it only from the firebug command line? Adding `debug(myFunctionName);` to my code throws an error for me.

Comment: The original website is no longer active. Most recent Wayback Machine snapshot from 2018: https://web.archive.org/web/20180412190544/http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging