# How to set a JavaScript breakpoint from code in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, breakpoints

I want to force the Chrome debugger to break on a line *via code*, or else using some sort of comment tag such as something like `console.break()`.

Comment: have you tried `debugger;` or just using regular breakpoints in the developer toolbar?

Comment: you mean set breakpoints from the code itself rather than setting them using the script watcher in the developer tools?

Comment: Or maybe better: [Set a breakpoint in XHR in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249696/set-a-breakpoint-in-xhr-in-chrome).

Comment: Not a duplicate.  "in Chrome" vs "in code" are two different things, and this question is applicable to many non-XHR scenarios.  Yes 1 of the answers in the other question answers this question, but others are not applicable.  I literally googled "set javascript breakpoint from code chrome" and this is the first result, and the other question isn't even on the first page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically control breakpoints in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271465/programmatically-control-breakpoints-in-javascript)

Comment: setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 5000)

Answer (score 1276, accepted):

You can use `debugger;` within your code.  If the developer console is open, execution will break.  It works in firebug as well.

Comment: A nice trick is to trigger the debugger after a few seconds: `setTimeout(function(){debugger;}, 3000);`

Comment: This is very helpful. Note also `debugger;` is supported in all major browsers. For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: @ScottyG MDN is less shiny, more useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: @JustusEapen Problem is that Javascript is single-threaded, so it can't interrupt running code.

Comment: @ScottyG an in terms of standards, it is a reserved statement with implementation defined effects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37549760/895245

Comment: Works for IE as well. With dynamically loaded scripts, trying to locate where to place the breakpoint to track what is calling an offending function can be difficult. I use `debugger;elusiveFunction();` step into the function and set the breakpoint.

Comment: For those who are getting trapped in an infinite loop as soon as the execution's started: Another simple trick is to comment all the entry code and execute, then simply open Chrome dev tools and add your breakpoint, now uncomment the commented lines and re-execute.

Answer (score 36):

You can also use `debug(function)`, to break when `function` is called.

[Command Line API Reference: debug](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#debug-function)

Comment: Very nice - appears to be Chrome only at this time, but that's my primary platform anyways. Now I just need to remember to stop calling my global debugging flag "debug"...

Comment: The Chrome Debugger Command Line API Reference actually contains some other quite helpful things I wasn't aware of. Thanks!

Comment: This link explains this approach in more details but lacks information about undebug() https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#function

Answer (score 27):

Set up a button click listener and call the `debugger;`

**Example**

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
 debugger;   
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/hBCH5/

**Resources on debugging in JavaScript**

- http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/05/the-three-ways-of-setting-breakpoints-in-javascript/
- http://berzniz.com/post/78260747646/5-javascript-debugging-tips-youll-start-using-today

Comment: That sets a breakpoint in the click handler, probably not what OP wanted

Comment: @PeterV I'd find it useful if I was just trying to open up my code to a place that was close to a block of code I was debugging... but didn't want to debug all the time... but yeah, if it's just to open the debugger... then there's a keypress for that.

Answer (score 15):

As other have already said, `debugger;` is the way to go.
I wrote a small script that you can use from the command line in a browser to set and remove breakpoint right before function call: 
http://andrijac.github.io/blog/2014/01/31/javascript-breakpoint/

Answer (score 9):

**`debugger` is a reserved keyword by EcmaScript and given optional semantics since ES5**

As a result, it can be used not only in Chrome, but also Firefox and Node.js [via `node debug myscript.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703227/895245).

The [standard says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.15):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> DebuggerStatement :
>     debugger ;
> ```
>
> Semantics
>
> Evaluating the DebuggerStatement production may allow an implementation to cause a breakpoint when run under a debugger. If a debugger is not present or active this statement has no observable effect.
>
> The production DebuggerStatement : debugger ; is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. If an implementation defined debugging facility is available and enabled, then
>
>    1. Perform an implementation defined debugging action.
>    2. Let result be an implementation defined Completion value.
> 2. Else
>
>    1. Let result be (normal, empty, empty).
> 3. Return result.

No changes in ES6.

Answer (score 7):

On the "Scripts" tab, go to where your code is. At the left of the line number, click. This will set a breakpoint.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of breakpoint in chrome]

You will then be able to track your breakpoints within the right tab (as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, he wants to be able to do it *in code*

Comment: If you load a JS script with an Ajax call, it will not show here, hence the need for a breakpoint in code.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, There is no Scripts tab anymore. Please update the image.

Comment: In some frameworks, like Drupal, the JS gets a cache-busting query string suffix added. If you flush caches, it often updates this suffix which can wipe out any breakpoints you have set on the previous load.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to debug JavaScript code. Following two approaches are widely used to debug JavaScript via code

1. Using `console.log()` to print out the values in the browser
   console. (This will help you understand the values at certain points
   of your code)
2. Debugger keyword. Add `debugger;` to the locations you want to
   debug, and open the browser's developer console and navigate to the
   sources tab.

For more tools and ways in which you debug JavaScript Code, are given in [this link by W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and there are many reasons you might want to do this. For example debugging a javascript infinite loop close to the start of the page loading, that stops the chrome developer toolset (or firebug) from loading correctly.

See section 2 of

http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/05/the-three-ways-of-setting-breakpoints-in-javascript/

or just add a line containing the word debugger to your code at  the required test point.

Answer (score 2):

> Breakpoint :-
>
> breakpoint will stop executing, and let you examine JavaScript values.
>
> After examining values, you can resume the execution of code (typically with a play button).
>
> Debugger :-
>
> The debugger; stops the execution of JavaScript, and callsthe debugging function.
>
> The debugger statement suspends execution, but it does not close any files or clear any variables.

```
Example:-
function checkBuggyStuff() {
  debugger; // do buggy stuff to examine.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `debug(functionName)` to debug functions as well.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#function

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend `debugger;` if you just want to kill and stop the javascript code, since `debugger;` will just temporally freeze your javascript code and not stop it permanently.

If you want to properly kill and stop javascript code at your command use the following:

`throw new Error("This error message appears because I placed it");`

Answer (score -1):

This gist [Git pre-commit hook to remove stray debugger statements from your merb project](https://gist.github.com/yeban/958687/f7c9675e86e1534077f9aedac6430e6c9b1c0e53)

maybe useful if want to remove `debugger` breakpoints while commit