# function doesn`t start after onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

Hi I tried to make a quiz for my friends. I set up function in my editor and it worked, when I move it to server, after button is hit nothing happens.

My html code is:

```
<div align="center"><img src="../obrazki/logo/logo4.jpg" class="logo"/></div>
<form  method="post" name="Formularz">
<strong>1. Question 1</strong><br>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="5" />a) answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="3" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="1" />c) answer 3<br/>
<br/>
 .
 .
 .
<strong>15. Question 15</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="5" />a) answer 1 <br/>
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="3" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="1" />c) answer 3<br/>
<br/>
</form>
<form method="post" name="formularz2" >
<strong>16. question16</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="9" />a) answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="7" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="5" />c) answer 3<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="3" />d) answer 4<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="1" />e) answer 5<br/>
<br/>
.
.
.
<strong>20. Question 20</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="9" />answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="7" />answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="5" />answer 3<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="3" />d) answer 4<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="1" />e) answer 5<br/>
<br/>
</form>
<button  type="button" onclick="checkRadio()">test</button>
<a  href="../index.htm"><p  align="center">Strona Główna</p></a>
<div id="suma"></div>
<div  id="suma2"></div>
```

My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkRadio() {
alert("hello World");
var form = document.getElementById('Formularz');
var form2 = document.getElementById('Formularz2');
var suma = 0;
var suma2= 0;
for ( var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++)
if (form.elements[i].checked) {
        suma=suma+parseInt(form.elements[i].value);
        document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = suma;
}
alert(suma);
for ( var i=0; i<form2.elements.length; i++)
if (form2.elements[i].checked) {
        suma2=suma2+parseInt(form2.elements[i].value);
        document.getElementById("suma2").innerHTML = suma2;
}
alert(suma2);
if (suma<9){
    if (suma2<20) {window.location="spider_bushi.htm"};
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="spider_courtier.htm"};
    else {window.location="spider_shugenja.htm"}; 
}
 else if (suma<17){
    if (suma2<10) {window.location="scorpion_ninja.htm"};
    else if (suma2<20) {window.location="scorpion_bushi.htm"};
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="scorpion_courtier.htm"};
    else {window.location="scorpion_shugenja.htm"};
}
else if (suma<26){
        if (suma2<20) {window.location="crab_bushi.htm"};
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="crab_courtier.htm"};
    else if (suma2<40) {window.location="crab_shugenja.htm"};
    else {window.location="crab_monk.htm"}; 
}
else if (suma<34){
    if (suma2<15) {window.location="mantis_bushi.htm"};
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="mantis_courtier.htm"};
    else {window.location="mantis_shugenja.htm"}; 
}
else if (suma<42){
    if (suma2<15) {window.location="unicron_bushi.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="unicron_courtier.htm"}; 
    else {window.location="unicron_shugenja.htm"}; 
}
else if (suma<51){
    if (suma2<20) {window.location="dragon_bushi.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="dragon_courtier.htm"};
    else if (suma2<40) {window.location="dragon_shugenja.htm"};
    else {window.location="dragon_monk.htm"}; 
}
else if (suma<60){
    if (suma2<20) {window.location="phoenix_bushi.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="phoenix_courtier.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<40) {window.location="phoenix_shugenja.htm"}; 
    else {window.location="phoenix_monk.htm"}; 
}
    else if (suma<68){
    if (suma2<16) {window.location="crane_bushi.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<31) {window.location="crane_courtier.htm"};
    else {window.location="crane_shugenja.htm"}; 
}
    else if (suma<76){
    if (suma2<16) {window.location="lion_bushi.htm"}; 
    else if (suma2<31) {window.location="lion_courtier.htm"};
    else {window.location="lion_shugenja.htm"};
}
else { alert("brak") }
} 
</script>
```

Scripts are working since putting a single "hello World" works when the page is loading. But button doesnt start checkRadio function at all, it doesnt even go to "hello world" line.
Please help.

Comment: is there any error on console

Comment: Try add to onclick 'return false'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few bugs in your code.

Firstly, you are using `;` unnecessarily in if-else block.

```
if (suma2<20) {window.location="crab_bushi.htm"};
    else if (suma2<30) {window.location="crab_courtier.htm"};
    else if (suma2<40) {window.location="crab_shugenja.htm"};
    else {window.location="crab_monk.htm"};
```

The statement var form = document.getElementById('Formularz'); is wrong. As There is no form id called `Formularz`.

I have corrected these bugs.

**HTML**:

```
<div align="center"><img src="../obrazki/logo/logo4.jpg" class="logo"/></div>
<form  method="post" name="Formularz" id="Formularz">
<strong>1. Question 1</strong><br>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="5" />a) answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="3" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="a" value="1" />c) answer 3<br/>
<br/>
 .
 .
 .
<strong>15. Question 15</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="5" />a) answer 1 <br/>
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="3" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="b" value="1" />c) answer 3<br/>
<br/>
</form>
<form method="post" name="formularz2" id="formularz2" >
<strong>16. question16</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="9" />a) answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="7" />b) answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="5" />c) answer 3<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="3" />d) answer 4<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="p" value="1" />e) answer 5<br/>
<br/>
.
.
.
<strong>20. Question 20</strong><br> 
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="9" />answer 1<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="7" />answer 2<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="5" />answer 3<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="3" />d) answer 4<br/>
<input  type="radio" name="w" value="1" />e) answer 5<br/>
<br/>
</form>
<button  type="button" onclick="checkRadio()">test</button>
<a  href="../index.htm"><p  align="center">Strona Główna</p></a>
<div id="suma"></div>
<div  id="suma2"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
function checkRadio() {
    alert("hello World");
    var form = document.getElementById('Formularz');
    var form2 = document.getElementById('Formularz2');
    var suma = 0;
    var suma2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++)
    if (form.elements[i].checked) {
        suma = suma + parseInt(form.elements[i].value,10);
        document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = suma;
    }
    alert(suma);
    for ( i = 0; i < form2.elements.length; i++)
    if (form2.elements[i].checked) {
        suma2 = suma2 + parseInt(form2.elements[i].value,10);
        document.getElementById("suma2").innerHTML = suma2;
    }
    alert(suma2);
    if (suma < 9) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "spider_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "spider_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "spider_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 17) {
        if (suma2 < 10) {
            window.location = "scorpion_ninja.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "scorpion_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "scorpion_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "scorpion_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 26) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "crab_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "crab_courtier.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "crab_shugenja.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "crab_monk.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 34) {
        if (suma2 < 15) {
            window.location = "mantis_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "mantis_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "mantis_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 42) {
        if (suma2 < 15) {
            window.location = "unicron_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "unicron_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "unicron_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 51) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "dragon_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "dragon_courtier.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "dragon_shugenja.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "dragon_monk.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 60) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "phoenix_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "phoenix_courtier.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "phoenix_shugenja.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "phoenix_monk.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 68) {
        if (suma2 < 16) {
            window.location = "crane_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 31) {
            window.location = "crane_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "crane_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else if (suma < 76) {
        if (suma2 < 16) {
            window.location = "lion_bushi.htm";
        } else if (suma2 < 31) {
            window.location = "lion_courtier.htm";
        } else {
            window.location = "lion_shugenja.htm";
        }
    } else {
        alert("brak");
    }
}
```

Even now the code won't work perfectly (as expected). The reason is **You are using two forms in the same page**. There are already lot of answers on handling multiple form at the same page at stack-overflow.

**Suggestions For JavaScript Code Debugging**:

Use Chrome debugger or Firebug for line by line JS Code Debugging . If the developer console is open, execution will break. It works in firebug as well.

**[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome)**

Also, you can always test your javascript code at **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)**. JS Fiddle is the best online IDE for javascript. It pin-point JS error and even displays the error msg.

Comment: Thank You very much again,  will try to improve this is ma first as advance JS code

Answer (score 0):

try below script you have put unwanted semicolons:

```
    function checkRadio() {
    alert("hello World");
    var form = document.getElementById('Formularz');
    var form2 = document.getElementById('Formularz2');
    var suma = 0;
    var suma2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++)
        if (form.elements[i].checked) {
            suma = suma + parseInt(form.elements[i].value);
            document.getElementById("suma").innerHTML = suma;
        }
    alert(suma);
    for (var i = 0; i < form2.elements.length; i++)
        if (form2.elements[i].checked) {
            suma2 = suma2 + parseInt(form2.elements[i].value);
            document.getElementById("suma2").innerHTML = suma2;
        }
    alert(suma2);
    if (suma < 9) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "spider_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "spider_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "spider_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 17) {
        if (suma2 < 10) {
            window.location = "scorpion_ninja.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "scorpion_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "scorpion_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "scorpion_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 26) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "crab_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "crab_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "crab_shugenja.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "crab_monk.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 34) {
        if (suma2 < 15) {
            window.location = "mantis_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "mantis_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "mantis_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 42) {
        if (suma2 < 15) {
            window.location = "unicron_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "unicron_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "unicron_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 51) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "dragon_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "dragon_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "dragon_shugenja.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "dragon_monk.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 60) {
        if (suma2 < 20) {
            window.location = "phoenix_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 30) {
            window.location = "phoenix_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 40) {
            window.location = "phoenix_shugenja.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "phoenix_monk.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 68) {
        if (suma2 < 16) {
            window.location = "crane_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 31) {
            window.location = "crane_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "crane_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else if (suma < 76) {
        if (suma2 < 16) {
            window.location = "lion_bushi.htm"
        }

    else
        if (suma2 < 31) {
            window.location = "lion_courtier.htm"
        }

    else
        {
            window.location = "lion_shugenja.htm"
        }

    }
    else {
        alert("brak")
    }
}
```

and html code:

```
    <div align="center"><img src="../obrazki/logo/logo4.jpg" class="logo"/></div>
<form method="post" name="Formularz" id="Formularz">
    <strong>1. Question 1</strong><br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="5"/>a) answer 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="3"/>b) answer 2<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1"/>c) answer 3<br/>
    <br/>
    .
    .
    .
    <strong>15. Question 15</strong><br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="5"/>a) answer 1 <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="3"/>b) answer 2<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="1"/>c) answer 3<br/>
    <br/>
</form>
<form method="post" name="formularz2" id="Formularz2">
    <strong>16. question16</strong><br>
    <input type="radio" name="p" value="9"/>a) answer 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="p" value="7"/>b) answer 2<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="p" value="5"/>c) answer 3<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="p" value="3"/>d) answer 4<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="p" value="1"/>e) answer 5<br/>
    <br/>
    .
    .
    .
    <strong>20. Question 20</strong><br>
    <input type="radio" name="w" value="9"/>answer 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="w" value="7"/>answer 2<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="w" value="5"/>answer 3<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="w" value="3"/>d) answer 4<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="w" value="1"/>e) answer 5<br/>
    <br/>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="checkRadio()">test</button>
<a href="../index.htm"><p align="center">Strona G?ówna</p></a>
<div id="suma"></div>
<div id="suma2"></div>
```

Comment: "Hello World" pop up. But after this nothing happens. I`am new at this so I don`t know how to check it propertly on console here it the link http://l5k.cba.pl/Kim%20jestes%20w%20Rokuganie/ankieta.htm I tried with firebug but it say`s nothing.

Comment: It worked, the problem was that there was "name" instead of "id". Thank You Very much :)