# Setting breakpoints on function calls in Chrome Dev. Mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Is there a way to set breakpoints when specific functions are *about* to execute?

It needn't be an explicit breakpoint - I just want execution to pause when a `console.log()` is about to be called.

Or should I resort to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome) method.

I prefer to accomplish this without modifying my code, or manually setting breakpoints at every `console.log`.

Comment: 1. As that topic said, put `debbuger;` before the `console.log`. 2. Open the dev-tool, switch to `Sources` tab and find that `console.log` in your code, click on its line number at the left and it should set a break point for you.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way of doing it without modifying my code. But I suppose I'll use `debugger;`.

Comment: I think the second way do not modify your code?

Comment: That is true. Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't want to modify the code, but also I don't want to have to manually click on every `console.log`. I was hoping Chrome Dev Tools had a way of just telling it to break in front of all `console.log` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's the trick. Create a custom logging function, put `debugger` in it and call `console.log` and you have what you wanted:

```
function log(message) {
    debugger;
    console.log(message) ;
}
```

### Edit:

You can also replace `console.log` by a similar fonction that calls the original:

```
var clog = console.log;
console.log = function(message) {
    if(message == '...') {
        debugger;
    }
    clog.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

This code will affect all log calls within your page. The check is to catch a certain message. Remove it to stop always.

Comment: What about breaking before `console.log` in code I didn't write. Like in a `backbone.js` that's hidden away somewhere. Is there a way of targeting those logs as well without editing the files?

Comment: I suppose I'd have to manually set those breakpoints in Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1):

How about call this at the very start that add a pause break for your every `console.log`?

This replace the original `console.log`, pause break first, then call the orignal `console.log` for you. And this will be apply on all `console.log` calls.

```js
(function () {
  var oldLog = console.log;
  console.log = function() {
    debugger;
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
  }
})();

console.log('hello');
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it break at the original call rather than inside that function? Granted, I could just step a couple times to get back to where I was, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Oh, I guess I can't, because it breaks where `debugger;` is. Nevermind.

Comment: I'm afraid not, but a good news, when paused, you can see there's a `Call Stack` on the right of the panel, should be just below `Watch`, you can click on it to jump out of current scope, and back to scope where  it is just about to be called.

Comment: For example, when see the stop on this snippet, you should see first line is `console.log`, and 2nd line is `(anonymous function)`, click on the second, you should see chrome dev guide you back out of `console.log` to the point its about to be called.