# Trace jQuery scripts by executing it one by one

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way, like in Chrome, where I can manually trace the first script that loads, then continue with the next one and see what it does, then continue on the third one and so on and so forth until all the scripts are loaded?

I'm not sure if there is a problem on the backend or just some scripts removing some contents of my HTML.

I'd like to see how scripts affect the appearance and behavior of site by executing it one by one so that I'll be able to detect which scripts affect certain HTML.

Comment: Which scripts?   Are you talking about the jQuery library or some specific function/script?  You can place a debugger line inside a script and step through the code (mostly) as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Best way is to apply breakpoints in your JS code and the 'scripts' that you are referring to(javascript in HTML I assume).

This can be done in both Firebug and Google Chrome JS Console. Every other place you feel something is wrong with the code add breakpoints and you can see the changes on your webpage with time.

Some references-

[Firebug Breakpoints Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome)

[Set Javascript Breakpoints in Chrome](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html)

[Debugging JS in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)