# Javascript console.log working with variable

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, console, ecmascript-6

Inside the console, you can simply declare variables and use them.

`var x = 'thing';`

> undefined

`x + 3;`

> 'thing3'

I want set that variable from a Javascript file, and use it in the console. That does not seem possible, so I hope somebody knows a solution for it.

In a javascript file, typing `console.log(var x = 'thing')` gives compilation errors in Gulp. I know I can just type `console.log(x)`, but I want to use the variable and play with it in the console.

How can I declare variables that I can use in the console?

Comment: You said many things but forgot to ask the concern ;)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a simple

```
var x = {thing: 'thing'};
console.log(x);
```

The `undefined` in the console comes from evaluating a statement that doesn't return anything. If you don't evaluate it in the console, but put it into your js files, there won't be any log.

> I'm trying to debug my webpage using `console.log`

Don't. Use a [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). You can statically [insert breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10050465/1048572) in your code with a `debugger;` statement.

> How can I interact with logged variables from a JS file in the console?

The best thing of breakpoints in a debugger is: you can interact with any variables in the scope of the breakpoint without even needing to log them.

Comment: I've never used the debugger, but obviously thats just my bad. Thx for the info, checking if that's what I need!

Comment: This is the answer. I can put a `debugger;` statement in my class and call it's variables as if they were global, except I have to call them with `this.varname` instead of `varname`. I have found a second solution;  if I set my variable in the `window` object, they are global and usable in the console as well. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `console.debug(myTest.test)`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the debugger rather than using global variables as it's not secure if you are able to access those variables in console. Use chrome while debugging. Open console and select the js file which you want to debug and put breakpoints.