# weird behavior- javascript events on chrome breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function registerForEvents() {
            var logElement = document.getElementById('log');

            function anchorCapture(e) {
                console.log("click captured");
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }
            var anc = document.getElementById("mylink");
            anc.addEventListener('click', anchorCapture, true);
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
                console.log("mouse down captured");
            }, true);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
                console.log("mouse up captured");
            }, true);

        }       
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:registerForEvents()">
    <a id="mylink" href="www.google.com">google</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

copy paste the above code and add a breakpoint in chrome at line 15 (i.e            console.log("mouse down captured");)

once the breakpoint is hooked press F8 (continue), you can see that other event handlers are ignored, why??

### Output

mouse down captured

If the breakpoint is at line 18 you would see

### Output

mouse down captured
mouse up captured
click captured

This would only appear if you hook breakpoints on mousedown events, seems to be fine with firefox (don't try on IE as callback methods are different)

Thanks

Comment: Try [debugger; - Set a javascript breakpoint in code - in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10050465/669527)

Comment: thanks, but here it's not the case where breakpoints are being hit or not! I don't understand why 'mousedown' events break the normal execution on google chrome on a breakpoint.